# Handling long mysql transactions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, transactions, database-deadlocks

I have a scenario where we kind of duplicate huge no. of data in a single transaction.

eg: I have one basket, which contains various types of fruits and vegetable objects. 
And I need to duplicate/replicate the whole set of objects in the new basket.

Currently, I am doing it in one single transaction duplicating the main object and its resources one by one, which works fine but. When there are simultaneous jobs running I get **deadlock** even in insert query.

Making the transaction short will work, but I want to revert/rollback if something goes wrong in replicating data.

Is there anything that I can do without making the transaction short to avoid the deadlocks?

Comment: Would be tempted to do this outside of active record objects.  A duplicate method on the basket that would create all the new records in straight sql -- two SELECT INTO statements that would create the new basket and its fruits and veggies.

Comment: Doing duplicating records is plain SQL query only. Its bulk insertion, the associated records are in thousands sometimes in lakhs.